# how to backup mysql db to a ftp

Tags: mysql, backup, ftp

how to backup  a mysql database regularly to a ftp server i mention ?

Any script for doing so ?

Comment: You can make backup a MySQL database regularly to FTP server with the help of MySqlBackupFtp (http://mysqlbackupftp.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could mount the remote ftp server using `curlftpfs` under `/mnt/ftpserver/` for example and then backup your database using

```
mysqldump --all-databases --opt > /mnt/ftpserver/mysql_backup.sql
```

Alternatively you can perform the `mysqldump` and then use `lftp` to push the backup file to the ftp server using something like

```
lftp -c "open -u <username>,<password> <servername>/<directory>; set ftp:rest-stor false; put mysql_backup.sql"
```

If you need more detail, please add a comment.

Comment: I would suggest mounting with curlftpfs, as it would make overall maintenance easier - especially if you want to push other files in the future.

Comment: simply we can do it, Mysql dumpl get .sql file & upload to ftp